# Command substitution - single quotes and spaces

Tags: bash, command-substitution

How can I make command substitution pass a list of single-quoted POSIX paths separated by spaces?

```
command1 $(command2)
command1 '/path/to/file 1' '/path/to/file 2' '/path/to/file 3'
```

How can I trace the expansion?

Comment: are single quotes really necessary; single quotes prevents expansion of any meta-character including $ and \.

Comment: @Ankit Yes, they are necessary.

Comment: Can it be a multiple executions of `command1` with each path?

Comment: @piotrekkr No, `command2` gives single-quoted POSIX paths separated by spaces.

Comment: @1.61803 yeah but if I make them separate and use `command1 'path 1'` multiple times would be it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see exactly what command is being run by using `set -x`. A rather silly example:

```
$ echo $(echo "foo 'bar baz' taz\\ jaz")
foo 'bar baz' taz\ jaz
```

will give:

```
++ echo 'foo '\''bar baz'\'' taz\ jaz'
+ echo foo ''\''bar' 'baz'\''' 'taz\' jaz
foo 'bar baz' taz\ jaz
```

This is somewhat hard to read, because of all the escaping. For example, that second word:

1. `''` becomes nothing.
2. `\'` becomes a single quote (`'`)
3. `'bar'` becomes `bar`

so that parameter is passed as `'bar`. You can confirm with something like this (assuming you have Data::Dump installed, which isn't the default, unfortunately) Note the `$(echo…` has been copied verbatim to the perl line:

```
$ perl -MData::Dump=pp -E 'pp @ARGV' $(echo "foo 'bar baz' taz\\ jaz")
("foo", "'bar", "baz'", "taz\\", "jaz")
```

What's happening here is that bash is doing word splitting (based off `$IFS`), not argument parsing. So you, unfortunately, probably have to use `eval`, and deal with all the risk that entails.

```
$ eval "echo $(echo "foo 'bar baz' taz\\ jaz")"
foo bar baz taz jaz
```

(Also, I'll note, if you can get your command to generate its output as a list of names, separated by NUL, that would be *easy* to deal with using `xargs -0` and further, fully safe).

Comment: `eval "command1 $(command2)"` it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are in the rare position to have a list of files that is in a format that `xargs` understands. So run

```
command1 | xargs command2
```

Note that on some unix variants, if the output of `command1` is huge, it will be impossible to run `command2` with all the file names due to the command line length limit. The downside of using `xargs` is that it will run the command several times instead of properly reporting an error. You can check the command line length limit with `getconf ARG_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
path1="/etc/passwd"
path2="/var/log/secure"

[root@localhost base_filters]# ls -l "$path1" "$path2"
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1876 Mar 10 22:15 /etc/passwd
-rw-------. 1 root root 2408 Apr  5 23:09 /var/log/secure
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I fully understand your question but maby this will help:

```
$ var=$(echo "'/path/to/dir 1' '/path/to/dir 2' '/path/to/dir 3'")
$ echo -n $var | sed "s/^'\(.*\)'\$/\1/g" | sed "s/' '/\x00/g" | xargs -0 command1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with IFS variable, so that space doesn't affect your script. I would store IFS in a variable and after completing actions of my script, i would restore the IFS.